# Adding items to object arrays

Tags: java, arrays

How do I add an item from the main method using the code below using my add method and a new object called queueLane1:

```
public class TrafficQueue {
    private Car [] carArray;
    private int numberOfcarsInQueue;


    public TrafficQueue(int numberOfcarsInQueue){
    carArray = new Car[numberOfcarsInQueue];


    }
    private class Car {} ; // define an empty Car class


    public void add(Car car){
    carArray[numberOfcarsInQueue] = car;
    numberOfcarsInQueue ++;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here


             TrafficQueue queueLane1 = new TrafficQueue(10);
```

the only solution I can think of so far is queuelane1.add("Toyota") but this returns an error as am adding a string to an expected car object.

How do i add a new item like a new car to my add method?

Comment: Make a new `Car` instance and pass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this,

```
public class TrafficQueue {
    private Car [] carArray;
    private int numberOfcarsInQueue;

    public TrafficQueue(int numberOfcarsInQueue){
    carArray = new Car[numberOfcarsInQueue];

    }

    static class Car 
    {
        public String name;

        public Car(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public void add(Car car){
    carArray[numberOfcarsInQueue] = car;
    numberOfcarsInQueue ++;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

             TrafficQueue queueLane1 = new TrafficQueue(10);
             Car toyota = new Car("Toyota");
             queueLane1.add(toyota);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very good answer! got me a new idea just don't why i didn't think about adding some information to this class!

Comment: if i wanted to use a toString method to return all items in the queue i came out with something like this :'code' public String toString()
  {
    String result = "";
    int scan = 0;
 
    while(scan < numberOfcarsInQueue)
    {
     if(carArray[scan]!=null)
     {
       result += carArray[scan].toString()+"\n";
     }
    scan++;
    }

    return result;

  }'code'

Comment: but this returns a value of "trafficqueue.TrafficQueue$Car@c53dce" , how can i return a list of all items in the queue?

Comment: Good idea, this is good practice for building up the class too. I don't know how how a toString() method would work, but you have the right idea. we also add a `getter` method to the Car class, `public String get(){
      return this.name.toString();
     }` the use in `main()`: `for(int i = 0; i < queueLane1.numberOfcarsInQueue; i++ )
              System.out.println(queueLane1.carArray[i].get());
    }`

Answer (score -1):

@Xvid, First, `add(Car car)` expects a Car object. So, you need to provide a constructor to your Car class and pass the name of in the parameter and save it in some attribute of the class:

```
public Car(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

Then, make your Car class static, like `private static class Car{`, then you may call the method queueLane1.add(new Car("Toyota"));

Comment: It's not, your answer looks right to me. I don't know either, I did basically the same thing you did, too. And you explained your answer well, too.

Comment: if i wanted to use a toString method to return all items in the queue i came out with something like this :'code' public String toString() { String result = ""; int scan = 0; while(scan < numberOfcarsInQueue) { if(carArray[scan]!=null) { result += carArray[scan].toString()+"\n"; } scan++; } return result; }'code'